# How to copy decoded frame from C to Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I used ffmpeg library to decode the video and got a frame buffer data.

I want to copy the frame buffer into Android byte array (format is RGB565).

How to copy the frame buffer data from C into Android byte array?

Have any one can give me some example or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `java.nio.ByteBuffer` for that:

```
ByteBuffer theVideoFrame = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frameSize);
...
CopyFrame(theVideoFrame);
```

And the native code could be something like:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_blah_blah_blah_CopyFrame(JNIEnv *ioEnv, jobject ioThis, jobject byteBuffer)
{
    char *buffer;   

    buffer = (char*)(ioEnv->GetDirectBufferAddress(byteBuffer));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "foo", "failed to get NIO buffer address");
        return;
    }

    memcpy(buffer, theNativeVideoFrame, frameSize);
}
```

To copy the data from the `ByteBuffer` to a `byte[]` you'd then use something like:

```
theVideoFrame.get(byteArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is a small problem, the correct function call may be is `char *buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, jobj);`.

Comment: Oh, right. The way I used to call `GetDirectBufferAddress` is for C++. In C you'd use the way you wrote in your comment.

Comment: I try to use your code, I found that in C the function execute successful, but back to Java throw the error is NULL, the code like this, `Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); 
ByteBuffer mByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(w * h * 2);
getFrame(mByteBuffer); // This is native function
mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(mByteBuffer); // Faild`

Is it copy failed frame?

Comment: It's possible that `copyPixelsFromBuffer` doesn't work with buffers allocated with `allocateDirect`. I don't know since I haven't tried it myself.